# docusign soap API embedded Signing WITHOUT iframes

Tags: api, soap, docusignapi

I have web app that I am adding DocuSign Embedded Signing to that is used both on Desktop as well as Mobile device.  I have been told that the iframe solution of SOAP API is unreliable (as I have also experienced). I am attempting to implement a solution and prefer using SOAP API.
I am using the SOAP API Embedded Signing example provided with the SDK.

If I assign the user security token to the iframe `src` attribute, the iFrame successfully loads the embedded view. *If* I try to `Response.Redirect` to that user token (just a URL) then the page comes up with the DocuSign Logo and error message that says the Session has expired.

What settings or changes need to be made so that I can use the SOAP API and redirect to browser rather than iframe? Is there a different way to request the user security token? do I need to set up different callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Embedding can only be used with iFrames at the moment.  We've had other developers express that they do not want to use iFrames here, and every time someone (like yourself) requests this it adds more reason for DocuSign to implement Embedding without iFrames, however at the moment it's simply not supported.  You have to use an iFrame for Embedding.

Comment: Is this true of the REST API as well?

Comment: Yes, both API protocols use iFrames for Embedding functionality